# How to visualize download and buffering progress?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application which contains video player. As per the requirement there should be two progress bars, one is the video downloaded and another one is the current position of video played (similar to YouTube videos where one is the downloaded progress of the video and the other is the current position of video). 
This is my code

```
mediaPlayer.BufferingProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    lblBuffering.Text = string.Format("Buffering {0:0.0%}",
    mediaPlayer.BufferingProgress);
};

mediaPlayer.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    lblDownload.Text = string.Format("Downloading {0:0.0%}",
    mediaPlayer.DownloadProgress);
};
```

I am not able get how much, or what percentage, of the video is downloaded.

Comment: There is a "DownloadProgress" property on the MediaElement.

Comment: It is always giving value as 100.

Comment: Are you playing off of the device already - if so it would be 100% always. Also maybe it is finishing that quick, have you checked what is on disk?

Comment: i have checked it in 2G network eventhough video is stopped due to slow network, download progress is 100.